# Analyze performance of for-loop of inserts in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, for-loop, intellij-idea, database-performance

I'm using a very simple for-loop to insert a lot of documents into a MongoDB collection, like this:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 100000; i++) {    
  db.test.insert( 
    { 
      id: i,
      f_name: "Alex", 
      l_name: "Jones"
    } 
  ) 
}
```

What would be the easiest way for me to see how long (in secons/milliseconds) this whole operation takes? I'm currently using IntelliJ IDEA, though if it's necessary, I'm fine with using another tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope below works-

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (var i = 1; i <= 100000; i++) {    
      db.test.insert( 
        { 
          id: i,
          f_name: "Alex", 
          l_name: "Jones"
        } 
      ) 
    }
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Time taken : "+endTime-startTime);
```